# Unable to parse XML from string

Tags: php, xml, laravel-5

I am trying to parse XML to array using https://github.com/orchestral/parser,  which is a XML Document Parser package for Laravel.

When i try to run the code i get an error that says:

`Unable to parse XML from string.`

Below is my test.xml file that I am trying to parse to array.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<api>
<user followers="5">
<id>1</id>
<email>crynobone@gmail.com</email>
</user>
</api>
```

and in my **Controller** this is how I am trying to parse the xml file

```
public function index()
{

$xml = XmlParser::load('test.xml');
$user = $xml->parse([
'id' => ['uses' => 'user.id'],
'email' => ['uses' => 'user.email'],
'followers' => ['uses' => 'user::followers'],
]);

print_r($user);

}
```

Does anyone have an idea why I am failing to parse the xml to array?

Comment: Your code looks pretty much like the original example, with the exception that you've got the xml-declaration in the first line. Have you tried leaving that out?

Comment: Given that Orchestra seems to throw that exception if an `simplexml_load_file` fails, are you absolutely sure that "test.xml" is being loaded correctly? Is it in the right directory? What happens if you use the full path to the file?

Comment: @igorshmigor i have tried leaving out the xml-declaration and it still gives me the same error message.

Comment: @MattGibson you are on point, if I use the full path it works. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

`XmlParser` [throws that error in the event of a basic failure](https://github.com/laravie/parser/blob/master/src/Xml/Reader.php) in `simplexml_load_file` with the path of the file you pass in. Given that you're not specifying the full path to the file, my guess would be that PHP's current directory isn't what you think it is, so the failure simply means that the parser can't find the file. Try using the full path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but Orchestral didn't provide a helpful hint in the error message.

As it is based on **SimpleXml**, I tried to load it with SimpleXml, using:

`<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("your_filename_with_full_path.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
?>`

That gave me the message

`parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: channel line 6 and item {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): simplexml_load_file(): file:/C:/.../storage/import/import.xml:242: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: channel line 6 and item at ..........\\AbcController.php:24)`

Well, way better explaining the reason.

Then I retried with Orchestral after fixing the XML and it immediately worked.